# How to use a function pointer with kthread_run?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a system call in Linux, and for it I want to create several threads using `kthread_run`. However when I pass the function pointer I get:

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘kthread_create_on_node’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
//method to do nothing for 100 milliseconds
int exist()
{
   mdelay(100);
   return 0;
}

//function pointer to exist
int (*exist_ptr)(void) = &exist;

//create processes and delta queues 
for (i = PROC_NUM - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    char name[6] = {'d', 'e', 'l', 't', 'a', i2};

    delta_entry de = {
        .task = kthread_run(exist_ptr, NULL, name);
        .list = linked_list;
        .delta_time =  PROC_NUM * MILSEC_GAP;
        .position = i2;
    }
    enqueue(&linked_list, &de, i2 - 1);
    i2++;
}
```

This obviously isn't all the code, becuase I didn't want to make the post too long. Thank you!

Comment: Just an aside: The `name` looks wrong. It is supposed to be a null-terminated printf-style format string. You should probably create the thread something like this: `.task = kthread_run(exist, NULL, "delta%d", i)` (after you have corrected the prototype of the `entry` function). Also, your posted code is full of syntax errors, e.g. semicolons in the `delta_entry de` initializer and a missing semicolon after the initializer. There are other horrible mistakes too. Are you sure you are ready for writing kernel code?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issues with the initializer! I've fixed them. Could you tell me about the other mistakes I made? No, I'm not ready for writing kernel code, but I figure the best way to learn is from experience. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Other mistakes. It's hard to be sure without knowing what your `enqueue` function actually does, but my suspicion is that it will expect the contents of `de` to remain valid after it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the linux source `kthread_run` is a macro calling `kthread_create_on_node`, which expects `int (*threadfn)(void *data)`.

`int exist()` takes an unspecified number of arguments as is therefore compatible with that function signature but `int (*exists_ptr)(void)` takes none. (`int exist()` and `int exist(void)` are synonymous only in C++. In C, `()` means unspecified promoted arguments and `(void)` means no arguments.)

Unprototyped function definitions are generally discouraged in modern C.
You should make the `exist` function's signature `int exists(void *unused)` right from the start.