# error: passing argument 1 of ‘kthread_create_on_node’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to develop a kernel module which has to execute a thread.

I am facing an error while compiling the module.

This is the module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>  // for threads

static struct task_struct *thread1;

int thread_fn(void) {   
    while(1) {
        printk("Thread_fuction is running ...\n");
        msleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}

int thread_init(void) {
    char our_thread[8]="thread1";
    printk(KERN_INFO "in init");
    thread1 = kthread_create(thread_fn,NULL,our_thread);
    if((thread1)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "in if");
        wake_up_process(thread1);
    }
    return 0;
}

void thread_cleanup(void) {
    int ret;
    ret = kthread_stop(thread1);
    if(!ret)
         printk(KERN_INFO "Thread stopped");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");   
module_init(thread_init);
module_exit(thread_cleanup);
```

And this is the error :

> thread.c:25:26: error: passing argument 1 of ‘kthread_create_on_node’
>   from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types] 
>   thread1 = kthread_create(thread_fn,NULL,our_thread);

Could anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a function pointer with kthread\_run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776473/how-to-use-a-function-pointer-with-kthread-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In kernel source code you can see that [`kthread_create_on_node()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/kernel/kthread.c#L272) function has first argument type: `int (*threadfn)(void *data)`. But your "threadfn" `int thread_fn (void)` roughly speaking is of type `int (*threadfn)(void)`.

So change `(void)` to `(void *data)`.